# limiting the number of global connections per second

Tags: firewall, iptables, connections

I want to limit the number of ALL incoming NEW connections on a port, not only from one IP, something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 3/s -j DROP
```

But I don't understand what's wrong. It worked once/twice, tried different limits and after that it now drops all new connections. (yes, I flushed the iptables each time before adding the rule in its various forms).

EDIT1: I have tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 5 --name SSH -j DROP
```

and it *seems* to work. Will this affect all connections or only the ones from the same IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of new connections to `3/s`, you have to change the rule target to be `ACCEPT` instead of `DROP`:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 3/s -j ACCEPT
```

You can read from `man iptables`:

```
limit
   This module matches at a limited rate using a token bucket filter.
   A rule using this extension will match until this limit is reached
```

So, your rule will drop all new connections until the limit is reached!!!

Comment: I have tried the rule you gave me and it seems it doesn't do what I want. I have tested it like this: 

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
     $f = fsockopen("IP_HERE", 22, &$err, &$err2, 1);
     echo "Opening #$i: ".($f ? "OK" : "FAILED, timeout 1s")."<br>";
    }

And it *instantly* creates 10 connections, when it should have created only 3 per second, right?

Comment: @Shocker: You need to create a `DROP` rule after this, or have the default `INPUT` policy set to `DROP` depending on your rules config. Otherwise, all connections will be accepted.